# Exclude files from broccoli Ember 2.0

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Hi im kind of new to ember, im looking for a way to tell broccoli not to include my img/ directory, i want to include some default images there which ill be programatically adding to the app

```
<img src='{{model.picture}}'/>
```

And i can see them ok in development but not in production since the name has a hash attaches due to brocolli task, how do i configure my BrocFile to exclude files in the directory i have checked the documentation here

https://github.com/rickharrison/broccoli-asset-rev

but i cant figure out where in my brocfile im expected to add that.

part of my brocfile

```
var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');
    var app = new EmberApp({
        modals: {
            layout: true,
            style: true,
            animation: 'scale'
        }
    });



    app.import({
        production: 'bower_components/raygun4js/dist/raygun.js'
    });
    app.import('bower_components/lodash/lodash.js');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Ember (and Ember-CLI), just make sure to scroll down far enough in the [broccoli-asset-rev](https://github.com/rickharrison/broccoli-asset-rev) documentation that you linked and you will reach the part most relevant to your circumstance. In particular, the provided 'Ember CLI addon usage' example should already be a close match for your case.

Adapting that to your stated problem and provided code, you would perhaps get something along the lines of

```
var app = new EmberApp({
    fingerprint: {
        exclude: ['img/']
    },
    modals: {
        layout: true,
        style: true,
        animation: 'scale'
    }
});
```

The [relevant Ember-CLI documentation section](http://www.ember-cli.com/user-guide/#fingerprinting-and-cdn-urls) also explains fingerprinting in slightly more detail.

Other than using the `exclude` option, you could

- set `enabled: false` if you don't actually need fingerprinting
- not include image extensions in general via something like `extensions: ['js', 'css', 'map']`

Answer (score 0):

This answer applies for Ember 2.x through at least 3.x.

Another approach is to use an addon that helps you easily exclude files. Installing
[ember-cli-funnel](https://github.com/kellyselden/ember-cli-funnel) and then specifying the file accomplishes this pretty nicely:

```
// ember-cli-build.js

let app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
  funnel: {
    exclude: [
      `${defaults.project.pkg.name}/routes/style-guide/**/*`,
      'addon-tree-output/some-addon/styles/**/*.scss'
    ]
  }
});
```